# Find a document in a collection by eliminating the array object values having some flag

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider a collection that has documents like (dummy values are mentioned below):

```
{
    id: "001",
    company: "abc",
    empDet: [
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'raj',
            age: 45,
            designation: 'clerk'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: false,
            name: 'ramya',
            age: 35,
            designation: 'manager'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: false,
            name: 'gabriel',
            age: 41,
            designation: 'asstManager'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'saran',
            age: 55,
            designation: 'attender'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'buela',
            age: 25,
            designation: 'cashier'
        }
    ],
    location: "delhi"
},
{
    id: "002",
    company: "xyz",
    empDet: [
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'ravi',
            age: 45,
            designation: 'consultant'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'reka',
            age: 35,
            designation: 'manager'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: false,
            name: 'geetha',
            age: 41,
            designation: 'asstManager'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: false,
            name: 'varun',
            age: 55,
            designation: 'attender'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'balu',
            age: 25,
            designation: 'clerk'
        }
    ],
    location: "mumbai"
},
{
    id: "003",
    company: "pqr",
    empDet: [
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'bobby',
            age: 45,
            designation: 'consultant'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'vinay',
            age: 35,
            designation: 'manager'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'faritha',
            age: 41,
            designation: 'asstManager'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: false,
            name: 'arun',
            age: 55,
            designation: 'attender'
        },
        {
            disableFlag: true,
            name: 'kayal',
            age: 25,
            designation: 'clerk'
        },
    ],
    location: "calcutta"
}
```

Using node.js and mongoose, I would like to retrieve the `xyz` company details but the values of `"empDet"` should have only values containing `disableFlag` as true. For example, the output I am expecting should be:

```
{
  id: "002",
  company: "xyz",
  empDet: [
    {
      disableFlag: true,
      name: 'ravi',
      age: 45,
      designation: 'consultant'
    },
    {
      disableFlag: true,
      name: 'reka',
      age: 35,
      designation: 'manager'
    },
    {
      disableFlag: true,
      name: 'balu',
      age: 25,
      designation: 'clerk'
    }    
  ],
  location: "mumbai"
}
```

How do I find or retrieve a document in a collection by eliminating the array object values having some flag as false using node.js and mongoose?

Comment: you should add a new property to your model, or you check in query result this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** pipeline operator in the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** should work for you in this case. This will recursively descend through the document structure and do some actions based on an evaluation of specified conditions at each level. The concept can be a bit tricky to grasp but the following example demonstrates this:

```
Model.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { "company" : "xyz" }
    },
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": [ "$disableFlag", false ] 
                },
                "then": "$$PRUNE",
                "else": "$$DESCEND"
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, results){
      // handle error
      console.log(results);
});
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e1398bf03613b4ad1b541"),
            "id" : "002",
            "company" : "xyz",
            "empDet" : [ 
                {
                    "disableFlag" : true,
                    "name" : "ravi",
                    "age" : 45,
                    "designation" : "consultant"
                }, 
                {
                    "disableFlag" : true,
                    "name" : "reka",
                    "age" : 35,
                    "designation" : "manager"
                }, 
                {
                    "disableFlag" : true,
                    "name" : "balu",
                    "age" : 25,
                    "designation" : "clerk"
                }
            ],
            "location" : "mumbai"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

-- **UPDATE** --
If you want to populate the employee details of employees belonging to xyz company, you can do use **[populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents)** with the latest version of mongoose which has the ability to recursively populate related documents in a query that has been added. But this requires a second query, and using populate differently like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    { 
        "$match": { "company" : "xyz" }
    },
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": [ "$disableFlag", false ] 
                },
                "then": "$$PRUNE",
                "else": "$$DESCEND"
            }
        }
    }
];
Model.aggregate(pipeline,
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;            
        Model.populate(results, {"path": "empDet.emp_id"}, function(err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 4));
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Really thanks a lot for your reply. But i forgot to mention that there will be one more field in the empDet(embedded) like emp_id which will be string and it references another collection. So i have to populate the employee details of employees belonging to xyz company as well(join the collection based on emp_id) and also the other values as mentioned in my query earlier(should have only values containing disableFlag as true). Sorry for not mentioning it earlier.(populate and aggregate both should be used,how can i achieve that?)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was able to both use aggregate and populate. I got the required output.   Model.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { "company" : "xyz" }
    },
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                        "$eq": [ "$disableFlag", false ]
                },
                "then": "$$PRUNE",
                "else": "$$DESCEND"
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, results){
   Model.populate(results,{path:'empDet.emp_id'},function(error,op){
   console.log(op);
   });
   
});

Comment: No worries. I have updated my answer with something that should nudge you in the right direction as I have no idea what your db schemas are like. But the concept is to call the populate method on the underlying result, the linked documentation should help if lost.

Comment: I am a new user to stackoverflow.com,i tried to accept your solution, but only after earning 15 reputation my vote will change the publically displayed post score. But really your reply was very helpful. Thanks Chridam